# Use application class instance variable inside get block

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using sinatra and I have the code:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    @logger = Logger.new "./log"
  end

  @logger.info "App started"          #this line works

  get "/info" do
    @logger.info "/info inquired"     #this does not work and complain @logger is nilClass
  end
end
```

Why `@logger` inside get block gives a nil object? How can I use `@logger` in this case?

---

PS. If I use a class variable like `@@logger`, the code above works. But why the instance variable is not working in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables attach themselves to whatever object is self at the time the instance variables spring into existence.

On the face of things, these are the values for self:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  #In here, self=App

  #When a block executes, it sees the value for self that existed in 
  #the surrounding scope at the time the block was CREATED:
  configure do #a block
    #So...in here self=App 
    @logger = Logger.new "./log"
  end

  @logger.info "App started"          #this line works

  get "/info" do #a block
    #Similarly, in here self=App
    @logger.info "/info inquired"     #@logger is NilClass
  end
end
```

Based on that state of things, you are right to be confused: it looks like when configure() executes the block that is passed to it, @logger will spring into existence and attach itself to App, then when get() calls the block that is passed to it, the @logger instance variable will refer to the instance variable attached to App.

But...ruby offers ways to change the value of self that a block sees when the block EXECUTES.  Here is an example:

```
p = Proc.new { puts self }
p.call

class Dog
  def initialize(a_proc)
    #In here, self is a Dog instance
    instance_eval &a_proc
  end
end

Dog.new p

--output:--
main
#<Dog:0x000001009b6080>
```

Based on your error, you have to suspect that Sinatra must be employing some ruby tricks to change self when it executes the block passed to get().

> How can we know this?

Ruby is the wild west of programming languages, so you can't ever know what is going to happen unless you look at the source code or good docs if they exist.  The source code is pretty convoluted.  I found this in the docs:

> Some knowledge of Sinatra’s internal design is required to write good
>   extensions. This section provides a high level overview of the classes
>   and idioms at the core of Sinatra’s design.
>
> Sinatra has two distinct modes of use that extensions should be aware
>   of:
>
> The “Classic” style, where applications are defined on main / the
>   top-level – most of the examples and documentation target this usage.
>   Classic applications are often single-file, standalone apps that are
>   run directly from the command line or with a minimal rackup file. When
>   an extension is required in a classic application, the expectation is
>   that all extension functionality should be present without additional
>   setup on the application developers part (like included/extending
>   modules).
>
> The “Modular” style, where Sinatra::Base is subclassed explicitly and
>   the application is defined within the subclass’s scope. These
>   applications are often bundled as libraries and used as components
>   within a larger Rack-based system. Modular applications must include
>   any desired extensions explicitly by calling register ExtensionModule
>   within the application’s class scope.
>
> Most extensions are relevant to both styles but care must be taken by
>   extension authors to ensure that extensions do the right thing under
>   each style. The extension API (Sinatra.register and Sinatra.helpers)
>   is provided to help extension authors with this task.
>
> Important: The following notes on Sinatra::Base and
>   Sinatra::Application are provided for background only - extension
>   authors should not need to modify these classes directly.
>
> Sinatra::Base **The Sinatra::Base class provides the context for all
>   evaluation in a Sinatra application. The top-level DSLish stuff exists
>   in class scope while request-level stuff exists at instance scope.**
>
> Applications are defined within the class scope of a Sinatra::Base
>   subclass. The “DSL” (e.g., get, post, before, configure, set, etc.) is
>   simply a set of class methods defined on Sinatra::Base. Extending the
>   DSL is achieved by adding class methods to Sinatra::Base or one of its
>   subclasses. However, Base classes should not be extended with extend;
>   the Sinatra.register method (described below) is provided for this
>   task.
>
> **Requests are evaluated within a new Sinatra::Base instance – routes,
>   before filters, views, helpers, and error pages all share this same
>   context.** The default set of request-level helper methods (e.g, erb,
>   haml, halt, content_type, etc.) are simple instance methods defined on
>   Sinatra::Base or within modules that are included in Sinatra::Base.
>   Providing new functionality at the request level is achieved by adding
>   instance methods to Sinatra::Base.
>
> As with DSL extensions, helper modules should not be added directly to
>   Sinatra::Base by extension authors with include; the Sinatra.helpers
>   method (described below) is provided for this task.

http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html

Comment: That makes sense. They should probably put the context info in the readme doc than somewhere regular user won't see. It's not even about writing extensions... it's just a regular app... but thanks!

Comment: @texasbruce, I think it may be down to marketing.  It's my impression that Sinatra is supposed to be the simple version of ruby on rails.  So if the Sinatra docs start talking about instance_eval and the different contexts in which blocks passed to the various methods will be executed, then Sinatra will seem complicated, and half the people will drop out.

Comment: if the user wrote some code and it does not even execute, the marketing effect would be even worse i believe

Comment: @texasbruce, you have a point there.  The Sinatra docs do say this: `Logging. In the request scope, the logger helper exposes a Logger instance: get '/' do
  logger.info "loading data"
  # ...
end`  Of course, if you read that you probably wouldn't remember or realize the significance of *In the request scope..*,

Comment: I am aware of that logger. It is the rack logger which can be set through Rack middleware `Rack::CommonLogger`, but it only exists in the request scope, not configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own logger in your `Sinatra::Base` and use it in your `get` block by doing:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :logger, Logger.new("./log")

  helpers do
    def logger; self.class.logger; end
  end

  logger.info self

  get "/info" do
    logger.info self
  end
  # ...
end
```

Or by using the class variable as you note in your edit. The log file from the above configuration shows why:

```
I, [2014-06-01T16:36:51.593033 #16144]  INFO -- : App
I, [2014-06-01T16:36:59.438078 #16144]  INFO -- : #<App:0x9aa919c @default_layout=:layout, @app=nil ...
```

In the first case, `self` is the application class, while in the `get` block, `self` is the instance of the class.

To clarify, in your example: Ruby interprets the first `@logger.info` (called from the context of your class) to be a class instance variable, while the second `@logger.info` is interpreted as an instance variable (which has not been defined). The variable you define in your `configure` block is set in the class context.

Comment: Why the first two are in the context of the class and the second is the instance? How can we know this? Is it a design flaw of the class?

Comment: With Sinatra it’s more common to use the [`settings` method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.5/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L918) rather than `self.class` directly, so your helper would look like `def logger; settings.logger; end`, or even do without the helper and just use `settings.logger` directly in your route code.